# Why can't Get-ADObject -identity against a GC use the SamAccountname, given that this attribute is

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Why can't Get-ADObject against a GC use the SamAccountname for the -identity parameter, given that this attribute is in the GC? The help for that cmdlet lists only DN and GUID as acceptable for -identity, and indeed only those work. But its just more common to need to query the GC on a list of logon names (SamAccountnames) that could be in any domain in the forest, which is my case here.

Is this a limitation of LDAP, the GC, the partial attribute set, or the PS cmdlets?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Get-ADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) if you're trying to get a list of user logon names, or [Get-ADComputer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=winserver2012-ps) if you're looking for systems which log on as well.

Or if you for some other reason need to use Get-ADObject, you can use a filter on SAMAccountNames instead: `Get-ADObject -f {SAMAccountName -like "*searchfilter*"}`

I'm not familiar with the design decisions behind why only certain attributes are valid. But, I would imagine that you cannot query against all AD Objects by SAMAccountName because most AD objects don't have a SAMAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

Use -property parameter to specify what you want to return

Comment: I'm sure the OP would appreciate an example.

Comment: Seriously? It's a simple cmdlet, and the name of parameter was given... and a wrong answer was voted up ... I can't understand people

Comment: @strongline Specifying Get-ADObject -Property will give you an error as the switch you're looking for is "Properties." More than that, trying to run Get-ADObject -Properties SAMAccountName still requires you to enter a filter, or an identity, neither of which can use an object's SAMAccountName, if it exists for that object. The OP specifically asked why the Identity parameter for Get-ADObject cannot be an object's SAMAccountName.

Comment: the whole purpose of serverfault, or any other forum, is to give one a pointer. If one expects others to hold his hand to for step by step, he/she should not even be in IT. What's your point about the difference between "property" and "properties"?  A typo, yes, but how hard it is to figure that out by anyone? To be frank, OP's question shouldn't even have been a question in the first place. The cmdlet is well documented, it's not hard to find the syntax - there is something called google.

Comment: @strongline the OP's question wasn't about how to syntactically use the cmdlet, it was about why a particular attribute wasn't a viable filter method,. They wanted to do *get-adobject -identity <samaccountname>* but can't because samaccountname isn't a valid identity filter. Telling them to do *get-adobject -identity <samaccountname> -properties samaccountname* isn't going to do what you're implying it will.